# DispatcherTimer.Tick statement's syntax query

Tags: c#

```
 dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick)
```

In above statement i want to know why is it += and not just =
I tried to find about it alot but just couldn't find any answer to it but just got to know that it triggers an event when a tick timer is completed.

Comment: It is `+=` because `Tick` is an event delegate and can have more than 1 subscriber. You can also use `-=` to unsubscribe.

Comment: Read everything about ``event``s and ``MulticastDelegate``s on the [MSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173175.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Tick` is an *event*. .NET events are basically a representation of the pub/sub model. Event handlers subscribe to a particular event. The event publisher can raise the event whenever they like, at which point all the event handlers are called. There can be more than one event handler for any particular event, hence `+=` instead of `=`.

It's worth understanding that events and delegates are slightly different beasts - although events use delegates to represent the handlers. See [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more details.